# Can an independent functional component re-render based on the state change of another?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

I'm new to React Native, and my understanding is that functional components and hooks are the way to go. What I'm trying to do I've boiled down to the simplest case I can think of, to use as an example. (I am, by the way, writing in TypeScript.)

I have two Independent components. There is no parent-child relationship between the two. Take a look:

[image: Navigation bar button and switch]

The two components are a login button on the navigation bar and a switch in the enclosed screen. *How can I make the login button be enabled when the switch is ON and disabled when the switch is OFF?*

The login button looks like this:

```
const LoginButton = (): JSX.Element => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const handleClick = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Away');
  };

  // I want the 'disabled' value to update based on the state of the switch.
  return (
    <Button title="Login"
            color="white"
            disabled={false}
            onPress={handleClick} />
  );
};
```

As you can see, right now I've simply hard-coded the `disabled` setting for the button. I'm thinking that will no doubt change to something dynamic.

The screen containing the switch looks like this:

```
const HomeScreen = () => {
  const [isEnabled, setEnabled] = useState(false);
  const toggleSwitch = () => setEnabled(value => !value);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Switch
        style={styles.switch}
        ios_backgroundColor="#3e3e3e"
        onValueChange={toggleSwitch}
        value={isEnabled}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

What's throwing me for a loop is that the `HomeScreen` and `LoginButton` are setup like this in the navigator stack. I can think of no way to have the one "know" about the other:

```
<MainStack.Screen name="Home" 
                  component={HomeScreen} 
                  options={{title: "Home", headerRight: LoginButton}} />
```

I need to get the login button component to re-render when the state of the switch changes, but I cannot seem to trigger that. I've tried to apply several different things, all involving hooks of some kind. I have to confess, I think I'm missing at least the big picture and probably some finer details too.

I'm open to any suggestion, but really I'm wondering what the simplest, best-practice (or thereabouts) solution is. Can this be done purely with functional components? Do I have to introduce a class somewhere? Is there a "notification" of sorts (I come from native iOS development). I'd appreciate some help. Thank you.

Comment: you want [react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started)

Comment: I'm not trying to start any kind of flame war, but is this how React Native works, that for a simple thing like this I have to incorporate another technology as well? Isn't there a built-in solution?

Comment: You need a global state that can be accessible from components you want to access. There are few state-management libraries like redux or mobx as said another comment. But you actually do not need to use another library if you'd like since this is a very basic state. You can use the react context api https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: yes they do, as @UğurEren mentioned but redux is widely used... I've posted an answer hope it helps... thanks..

Comment: You can pass in the state of the parent `loginState` to the child element `button`  and control the state of the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to choose the context method, you need to create a component first that creates our context:

```js
import React, { createContext, useReducer, Dispatch } from 'react';

type ActionType = {type: 'TOGGLE_STATE'};

// Your initial switch state
const initialState = false;

// We are creating a reducer to handle our actions
const SwitchStateReducer = (state = initialState, action: ActionType) => {
  switch(action.type){
    // In this case we only have one action to toggle state, but you can add more
    case 'TOGGLE_STATE':
      return !state;

    // Return the current state if the action type is not correct
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

// We are creating a context using React's Context API
// This should be exported because we are going to import this context in order to access the state
export const SwitchStateContext = createContext<[boolean, Dispatch<ActionType>]>(null as any);

// And now we are creating a Provider component to pass our reducer to the context
const SwitchStateProvider: React.FC = ({children}) => {
  // We are initializing our reducer with useReducer hook
  const reducer = useReducer(SwitchStateReducer, initialState);
  
  return (
    <SwitchStateContext.Provider value={reducer}>
      {children}
    </SwitchStateContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default SwitchStateProvider;
```

Then you need to wrap your header, your home screen and all other components/pages in this component. Basically you need to wrap your whole app content with this component.

```js
<SwitchStateProvider>
  <AppContent />
</SwitchStateProvider>
```

Then you need to use this context in your home screen component:

```js
const HomeScreen = () => {
  // useContext returns an array with two elements if used with useReducer.
  // These elements are: first element is your current state, second element is a function to dispatch actions
  const [switchState, dispatchSwitch] = useContext(SwitchStateContext);

  const toggleSwitch = () => {
    // Here, TOGGLE_STATE is the action name we have set in our reducer
    dispatchSwitch({type: 'TOGGLE_STATE'})
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Switch
        style={styles.switch}
        ios_backgroundColor="#3e3e3e"
        onValueChange={toggleSwitch}
        value={switchState}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

And finally you need to use this context in your button component:

```js
// We are going to use only the state, so i'm not including the dispatch action here.
const [switchState] = useContext(SwitchStateContext);

<Button title="Login"
        color="white"
        disabled={!switchState}
        onPress={handleClick} />
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm working my way through this, but TypeScript (which I'm learning at the same time I'm learning React Native) is giving me a hard time with its error messages. I'm hopeful though.

Comment: @Mario Sorry, seems like that was my mistake, i've edited my answer to fix typescript errors

Comment: This is now working for me, with one small change: namely, the Button `disabled` attribute's value should be negated: `disabled={!switchState}`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out another way of tracking state, for this simple example, that doesn't involve using a reducer, which I'm including here for documentation purposes in hopes that it may help someone. It tracks very close to the accepted answer.

First, we create both a custom hook for the context, and a context provider:

```js
// FILE: switch-context.tsx

import React, { SetStateAction } from 'react';

type SwitchStateTuple = [boolean, React.Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>];

const SwitchContext = React.createContext<SwitchStateTuple>(null!);

const useSwitchContext = (): SwitchStateTuple => {
    const context = React.useContext(SwitchContext);
    
    if (!context) {
        throw new Error(`useSwitch must be used within a SwitchProvider.`);
    }    
    
    return context;
};

const SwitchContextProvider = (props: object) => {
    const [isOn, setOn] = React.useState(false);
    const [value, setValue] = React.useMemo(() => [isOn, setOn], [isOn]);
    
    return (<SwitchContext.Provider value={[value, setValue]} {...props} />);
};

export { SwitchContextProvider, useSwitchContext };
```

Then, in the main file, after importing the `SwitchContextProvider` and `useSwitchContext` hook, wrap the app's content in the context provider:

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <SwitchContextProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        {MainStackScreen()}
      </NavigationContainer>
    </SwitchContextProvider>
  );
};
```

Use the custom hook in the Home screen:

```js
const HomeScreen = () => {
  const [isOn, setOn] = useSwitchContext();

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Switch
        style={styles.switch}
        ios_backgroundColor="#3e3e3e"
        onValueChange={setOn}
        value={isOn}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

And in the Login button component:

```js
const LoginButton = (): JSX.Element => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [isOn] = useSwitchContext();

  const handleClick = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Away');
  };

  return (
    <Button title="Login"
            color="white"
            disabled={!isOn}
            onPress={handleClick} />
  );
};
```

I created the above by adapting an example I found here:

https://kentcdodds.com/blog/application-state-management-with-react

The whole project is now up on GitHub, as a reference:

https://github.com/software-mariodiana/hellonavigate

Answer (score -1):

Crete a `reducer.js` :

```
import {CLEAR_VALUE_ACTION, SET_VALUE_ACTION} from '../action'

const initialAppState = {
    value: '',
};

export const reducer = (state = initialAppState, action) => {
    if (action.type === SET_VALUE_ACTION) {
        state.value = action.data
    }else if(action.type===CLEAR_VALUE_ACTION){
        state.value = ''
    }
    return {...state};
};
```

Then `action.js`:

```
export const SET_VALUE_ACTION = 'SET_VALUE_ACTION';
export const CLEAR_VALUE_ACTION = 'CLEAR_VALUE_ACTION';

export function setValueAction(data) {
    return {type: SET_VALUE_ACTION, data};
}

export function clearValueAction() {
    return {type: CLEAR_VALUE_ACTION}
}
```

In your components :

```
...
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
...
function ComponentA({cartItems, dispatch}) {

}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        value: state.someState,
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ComponentA);
```

You can create more components and communicate between them, independently.